# model class is not detected in zend

Tags: zend-framework

I am making the simple quickstart project using Netbeans IDE 6.9.1 I've made the GuestBookMapper class in models folder which maps to the DBTable class in models/dbTable/ folder in there Guests class is present which is a DbTable class of table guests. But it is showing the following error.
Fatal error: Class 'Application_Model_GuestbookMapper' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\quickstart\application\controllers\IndexController.php on line 13

Here is my application.ini

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.db.adapter = 'PDO_MYSQL'
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = ""
resources.db.params.dbname = "guestbook.db"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

And here is my GuestbookMapper class

```
<?php  
class Application_Model_GuestbookMapper
{
    protected $_dbTable;
    public function setDbTable($dbTable)
    {
        if (is_string($dbTable)) {
            $dbTable = new $dbTable();
        }
        if (!$dbTable instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Abstract) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid table data gateway provided');
        }
        $this->_dbTable = $dbTable;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDbTable()
    {
        if (null === $this->_dbTable) {
            $this->setDbTable('Application_Model_DbTable_Guests');
        }
        return $this->_dbTable;
    }

    public function save(Application_Model_Guestbook $guestbook)
    {
        $data = array(
            'email'   => $guestbook->getEmail(),
            'comment' => $guestbook->getComment(),
            'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        );

        if (null === ($id = $guestbook->getId())) {
            unset($data['id']);
            $this->getDbTable()->insert($data);
        } else {
            $this->getDbTable()->update($data, array('id = ?' => $id));
        }
    }

    public function find($id, Application_Model_Guestbook $guestbook)
    {
        $result = $this->getDbTable()->find($id);
        if (0 == count($result)) {
            return;
        }
        $row = $result->current();
        $guestbook->setId($row->id)
                  ->setEmail($row->email)
                  ->setComment($row->comment)
                  ->setCreated($row->created);
    }

    public function fetchAll()
    {
        $resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll();
        $entries   = array();
        foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
            $entry = new Application_Model_Guestbook();
            $entry->setId($row->id)
                  ->setEmail($row->email)
                  ->setComment($row->comment)
                  ->setCreated($row->created);
            $entries[] = $entry;
        }
        return $entries;
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Is the class `Application_Model_GuestbookMapper` stored in the file `application/models/GuestbookMapper.php`? That's where the standard resource autoloader is expecting it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
$moduleLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => 'Application',
        'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH 
        ));
```

in init() method in GuestController.php file.